# Cloud Run - Custom Domain Mapping with Wildcard Subdomain

Tags: google-cloud-run

Our app utilizes subdomains like `customerA.mydomain.com` or `customerB.mydomain.com`, wherein the subdomains are unique publicly accessible storefronts that are "created" by our customers. We would like to route all `*.mydomain.com` to a particular Cloud Run service. We have already set up a wildcard subdomain CNAME in the DNS records to route to `ghs.googlehosted.com.`, but how can we make Cloud Run accept requests from any subdomain?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to map each subdomain to a service using API or gcloud commands. For example:

```sh
gcloud run domain-mappings create --service=myapp  --domain=www.example.com
```

Technically this is because each service is with provisioned HTTP SSL certificate (built-in and provided out-of-the box for you without any charge), and there is no `wildcard certificate` issued by Google for your domain. That's why you cannot map a *(star) to a service. This means you need to instruct GCP Cloud Run service to map and issue a certificate request for each of your subdomain.

Also reach out to your Account Manager, as there are other limits on Cloud Run such as:

> Maximum number of SSL certificates: 50 per top domain and per week

Comment: Thanks, but this also means that we have to wait for Cloud Run to provision the certificate so users won't be able to access their storefront immediately after account creation. After some research, someone mentioned Cloud Run for Anthos as a possible solution?

Comment: @arao6 did you find a solution for this? I am looking in to the exact same problem currently.

Comment: They will be able to access the storefront on a temporary URL immediately, and as soon as the certificates are provisioned you can notify them about their final URL.

Comment: @Andreas nope, we ended up provisioning a VM that acted as a reverse proxy to our Cloud Run. The server would attach a header based on the subdomain. There are lots of tutorials for this. Alternatively you can just use the VM with Let's Encrypt for free, but you have a manual process of updating the cert every 3 months

Comment: Could you be more specific about your solution? I'm trying to do the same, but I can't find any tutorial about this other than scripts to automate the domain mapping. Are you using a load balancer? Do you provide a self-managed wildcard certificate? The VM you refer to is a Compute Engine instance? Can you provide keywords to search for these tutorials? I'm new to GCP networking and I'm kinda lost.

Comment: What he meant was to use a reverse proxy like NGINX in front of cloud run and do the url mapping. Extract the subdomain in url rewrite rules and pass it to cloud run service. That ways you can still have a single url pointing to cloud run but can handle any number of subdomain urls via nginx.

Comment: Now in 2023, GCP can provide certificates for wildcard domains using DNS authorization (https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/deploy-google-managed-dns-auth). So now the question that still remains: how then do you *point* a *.example.com to Cloud Run?